# Problema comunicación por socket , se envia y queda colgado

Tags: javascript, php, socket

estoy realizando una comunicación entre una api en php  y un modulo echo en node, la comunicacion es a traves de socket. Los datos que se envian de la API al modulo (realizado en node) están llegando correctamente el problema es que luego del envio de datos , deberia redireccionarme a una pagina de mi aplicacion y no lo está haciendo queda colgado:

[La linea de codigo donde debe redireccionar se encuentra al finalizar el try antes del comienzo de catch]
API ENVIA DATOS:

```
 public function saveValidation(){            

        try {

            $periodocron='';
            $socket = new SocketModel(CONFIG['NODE_SOCKET_PORT_VEE'], CONFIG['CONTAINER_NAME_VEE']);
        
        
            if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                $validationRule = ValidationRule::find($_GET['id']);                
                $validationRule->period = strval($_POST['periodicidad']);
          
                $date_min = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['date_min']);
                $date_min =  $date_min->format('Y-m-d H:i:s ');
                $hasta = null;
               if(isset($_POST['date_max'])){

                  $hasta = strval($_POST['date_max']);  
                }


                $validationRule->dateTime_from = $date_min;
                $validationRule->execution_hour = $date_min;

                // $validationRule->Execution_Hour = $_POST['hora'];
                
                $validationRule->save();
                if( $validationRule->period  === "Ingreso"){
                 $periodocron = 'now';

                }else if($validationRule->period === "Semanal"){
                 $day = intval($_POST['days']);
                $executionH = str_replace(':', '' , strval($_POST['executionTime']));
                $minutes = substr($executionH, -2);
                $hours = substr($executionH, 0, 2);
                $periodocron =  $minutes. ' '. $hours. ' * * ' . $day ;
    
                }else if($validationRule->period === "Mensual"){
                 $executionH = str_replace(':', '' , strval($_POST['executionTime']));
                $minutes = substr($executionH, -2);
                $hours = substr($executionH, 0, 2);
                $periodocron = $minutes. ' '. $hours . ' ' . intval($_POST['monthlyType']) . ' * *';
                }else if ($validationRule->period === "Diario"){
                $executionH = str_replace(':', '' , strval($_POST['executionTime']));
                $minutes = substr($executionH, -2);
                $hours = substr($executionH, 0, 2);
                $periodocron = $minutes.' '. $hours . ' * * *';
                }else if ($validationRule->period === "Instantaneo"){

                }
                
            if ($_POST['validationGroups']){
                    $validationRule->validationGroup()->sync($_POST['validationGroups']);
               }               
             
                if($_POST['point']){
                    $validationRule->validationLocation()->sync($_POST['point']);
                }
              $data = array(
            'integrate' => $_GET['tipo'],
            'client_db_dbo' => $_SESSION['client_db_dbo'],
            'user_ps' => $_SESSION['user_ps'],
            'rol_id' => $_SESSION['rol_id'],
            'client_type' => $_SESSION['client_type'],
            'client_host' => $_SESSION['client_host'],
            'client_user' => $_SESSION['client_user'],
            'client_pass' => $_SESSION['client_pass'],
            'client_db' => $_SESSION['client_db'],
            'client_env' => $_SESSION['client_env'],
            'periodo' => $periodocron,
            'validationrule_id' => $validationRule->id,
            'fDesde' => $date_min,
            'fHasta' => $hasta
        );

     $socket->send($data);
     $socket->close();

            }else{
                 $validationRule = new ValidationRule();

                $date_min = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['date_min']);
                $date_min =  $date_min->format('Y-m-d H:i:s ');
                // $execution_hour = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $_POST['date_min'] . ' ' . $_POST['executionTime']);
                // $execution_hour = $execution_hour->format('Y-m-d H:i:s ');
                // echo  json_encode($_POST['executionTime']);
                // die;
          
                $validationRule->name = strval($_POST['description']);
                $validationRule->active = intval($_POST['status']);
                $validationRule->type = intval($_POST['validationTypeFun']);
                $validationRule->period = strval($_POST['periodicidad']);
             

                $validationRule->dateTime_from = $date_min;
                $validationRule->execution_hour = $date_min;
                $validationRule->validation_file = intval($_POST['validationFile']);


                //        echo ($validationRule);
                // die;
                $validationRule->save();

                // $execution_hour = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $_POST['date_min'] . ' ' . $_POST['executionTime']);
                // $execution_hour = $execution_hour->format('Y-m-d H:i:s ');
                // echo  json_encode($_POST['executionTime']);
                // die;

               

                if ($_POST['validationGroups']){
                    $validationRule->validationGroup()->sync($_POST['validationGroups']);
                }
                
                if($_POST['point']){
                    $validationRule->validationLocation()->sync($_POST['point']);
                }

                
                if ($_POST['magnitudesTableD']){               
                    foreach (json_decode($_POST['magnitudesTableD']) as $value)
                    {
                        // echo  $value->Descripcion;
                        $validationMagnitudes = new  ValidationMagnitudes;
                        $validationMagnitudes->id_validation_rule = intval($validationRule->id);
                        $validationMagnitudes->name = strval($value->Descripcion);
                        $validationMagnitudes->type = intval($_POST['validationFile']);
                        $validationMagnitudes->channel = intval($value->CanalId);
                        $validationMagnitudes->min = floatval($value->UmbralMin);
                        $validationMagnitudes->max = floatval($value->UmbralMax);
                        $validationMagnitudes->save();
                    
                    }   
                } else {
                    foreach (json_decode($_POST['magnitudesTableC']) as $value)
                    {
                        // echo  $value->Descripcion;
                        $validationMagnitudes = new  ValidationMagnitudes;
                        $validationMagnitudes->id_validation_rule = intval($validationRule->id);
                        $validationMagnitudes->name = strval($value->Descripcion);
                        $validationMagnitudes->type = intval($_POST['validationFile']);
                        $validationMagnitudes->min = floatval($value->UmbralMin);
                        $validationMagnitudes->max = floatval($value->UmbralMax);
                        $validationMagnitudes->formula = strval($value->Formula);
                        $validationMagnitudes->channel = intval($value->CanalId);
                        $validationMagnitudes->channel_active = intval($value->CanalActiveId);
                        $validationMagnitudes->register_id = intval($value->register_id);
                        $validationMagnitudes->incremental = intval($value->incremental);
                        $validationMagnitudes->save();
                        
                        foreach ($value->variables as $value)
                            {
                                $variables = new  ValidationVariablesMagnitudes;
                                $variables->id_validation_magnitudes =  intval($validationMagnitudes->id);
                                $variables->channel =  intval($value->channel->id);
                                $variables->name = strval($value->name);   
                                $variables->save();             
                            } 
                    }   
                }                  
               $hasta = null;
                if(isset($_POST['date_max'])){

                  $hasta = strval($_POST['date_max']);  
                }          
                 if( $validationRule->period  === "Ingreso"){
                 $periodocron = 'now';

                }else if($validationRule->period === "Semanal"){
                 $day = intval($_POST['days']);
                $executionH = str_replace(':', '' , strval($_POST['executionTime']));
                $minutes = substr($executionH, -2);
                $hours = substr($executionH, 0, 2);
                $periodocron =  $minutes. ' '. $hours. ' * * ' . $day ;
    
                }else if($validationRule->period === "Mensual"){
                 $executionH = str_replace(':', '' , strval($_POST['executionTime']));
                $minutes = substr($executionH, -2);
                $hours = substr($executionH, 0, 2);
                $periodocron = $minutes. ' '. $hours . ' ' . intval($_POST['monthlyType']) . ' * *';
                }else if ($validationRule->period === "Diario"){
                $executionH = str_replace(':', '' , strval($_POST['executionTime']));
                $minutes = substr($executionH, -2);
                $hours = substr($executionH, 0, 2);
                $periodocron = $minutes.' '. $hours . ' * * *';
                }else if ($validationRule->period === "Instantaneo"){

                }

            $data = array(
            'integrate' => $_GET['tipo'],
           'client_db_dbo' => $_SESSION['client_db_dbo'],
            'user_ps' => $_SESSION['user_ps'],
            'rol_id' => $_SESSION['rol_id'],
            'client_type' => $_SESSION['client_type'],
            'client_host' => $_SESSION['client_host'],
            'client_user' => $_SESSION['client_user'],
            'client_pass' => $_SESSION['client_pass'],
            'client_db' => $_SESSION['client_db'],
            'client_env' => $_SESSION['client_env'],
            'periodo' => $periodocron,
            'validationrule_id'=> $validationRule->id,
            'fDesde' =>  $date_min,
            'fHasta' => $hasta,
        );

     $socket->send($data);
     $socket->close();
              
    } 
    return $this->redirect('validaciones'); 
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            echo $th->getMessage();
        }    
    }
```

Modulo en node recibe correctamente la informacion enviada por el socket:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);

// modules
const LoggerModule = require('./modules/logger');
const ResultsModule = require('./modules/results/results');

// configuration
const { config } = require('./config');
const APP_NAME = 'optimum-vee';

// utils
const Auxiliar = require('./utils');
const {CronWatch} = require('./modules/results/utils/CronWatch');
const IP_ADDRESS = Auxiliar.ip();

// middlewares
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    next();
});

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));

// error handlers
const ErrorHandlers = require('./utils/middleware/errorHandlers');
const notFound = require('./utils/middleware/notFoundHandler');

// auth handlers
const AuthHandler = require('./utils/middleware/AuthHandler');
new AuthHandler({ app });

// databases

const net = require('net');
const { setFecha, newReadingValidationCron } = require('./tasks/ValidacionDeLectura');
const server = net.createServer()
//Connection Socket

console.log('dirname ', __dirname);
CronWatch();
 
server.listen(config.socketPort, config.socketIp, () => {})
server.on('connection', (sock) => {
  var strBuff = ''
  sock.on('data', async function (data) {
    data = data.toString()
    strBuff += data;
     sock.write(JSON.stringify({'code':200,'horaServer':new Date()}));
     sock.on('close', function(data) {
        let index = sockets.findIndex(function(o) {
            return o.remoteAddress === sock.remoteAddress && o.remotePort === sock.remotePort;
        });

        if (index !== -1) sockets.splice(index, 1);
    });
```

Comment: Habrá que liberar el socket para que continúe?

Comment: como se hace eso?